# Null object is preventing JSON decodable from working in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, decodable

Is there a way to get around null objects in a way to ensure decodable JSON works? I have attached image of the JSON.

```
import UIKit

struct SearchResultData: Decodable  {
    let server_response_time: Int
    let data: [SearchResultType]
    let success: Bool
}

struct SearchResultType: Decodable  {
    let group: String
    let data: [Movie]
}

struct Movie: Decodable {
    let title: String
}
```

[image]

I get this error when running the app.

> Failed to decode JSON: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "title", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 2", intValue: 2), CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"title\", intValue: nil) (\"title\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Make the types optional to handle nil values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change the types that could have nils to optionals in your `structs`

```
struct SearchResultData: Decodable  {
    let server_response_time: Int
    let data: [SearchResultType]
    let success: Bool
}

struct SearchResultType: Decodable  {
    let group: String
    let data: [Movie]
}

struct Movie: Decodable {
    let title: String? // this is nullable variable, 
}
```

> debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"title\", intValue: nil) (\"title\").", underlyingError: nil))<-- as this line says

Answer (score 3):

This

> : "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"title\", intValue: nil) (\"title\").", underlyingError: nil))

means that `title` is `nil` in some parts so make it

```
let title: String?
```

You may also need

```
let data: [SearchResultType?]
```

as `data` key contains some null values also

Comment: Thanks so much! Can't believe I overlooked that. 

Do you have any idea why I cannot seem to access the second nested level of data: [Movie]?

For some reason I can't access this or any of the movie properties:
self.searchResults = searchResult.data.data

The first data autocompletes, but then can't access anything?